# How to detect the item that is being "grabbed" by a player in the GUI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the GUIs of chests, furnaces, anvils, etc., or just your own inventory, you click on an item to pick it up, and click again to put it into a slot of your inventory or the container block.

What is the NBT tag that returns a copy of the data of the item currently selected and moving with the cursor, and how would we modify it?

I am curious because several maps involve clicking on items to navigate an interface, and I am curious because the items that the player clicks on don't end up "grabbed."

Comment: Probably none. Those items are handled a bit strangely. BTW, are you in 1.15.2 or in the snapshots? There were a few bug fixes and changes related to this recently.

Comment: I think you can remove them with `/clear` (in newer versions), but `/clear 0` might not include them in the count. But it might also do it, I'm not sure. I'll try stuff tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Not an exact answer but just an idea.  You could save the containers nbt with the data command and then check if its different in the next tick using functions or repeating command blocks.

Comment: What commands could you use to do such a thing?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 This video will help for comparing data [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gY0Q1hLu-ms&t=108s) and this video will help for storing data [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uOd5mCqIJ4) if you need any other help pleas ask.  I also suggest watching cloud wolf on youtube for command and datapack tutorials.  The videos I linked are his.  Anything from 1.13 and later is generally up to date.